# Why doesn't my animation have the effects applied after compositing?

Tags: rendering, animation, node-editor, compositing-nodes

So, I have a video in MP4 format, and I put it into the compositing workspace. I want to render this video with the effects I applied in compositing, but every time the effects are not there, just like when I try to render an image. In that case, I have to switch to the viewer node to see the effect and save it as an image. However, when I try to do the same with an animation, I can't save it as a video; it only saves as a single image. How do I render the video with these effects?And u can see that effect in viewer node but not in render result[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]